# React native - Android - Alert dialog cancelable false not working

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Am new to react native, Am trying to show an alert dialog with `cancelable : false` It is not working. When I touch outside my dialog it is closing. Help me with this.

snippet:

```
Alert.alert(
 '',
 Strings.str_unexpected_error,
 [
   {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.unexpectedBehavior()},
 ],
 {
   cancelable: false
 }
);
```

Comment: Hey, same code is working perfectly for me. Which version of react-native are you using?

Comment: @Jickson am using `"react-native": "0.32.0"`

Comment: I am using "0.36.0" and its working fine here

Comment: @Jickson Will update and check it.. :)

Comment: cancelable was added in 0.33.0 version https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.33.0

Comment: Super, Thanks @Jickson updated react-native to `0.36`, It is working fine now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as answer, might help someone later.

I was using `"react-native": "0.32.0"`. This issue was fixed in version `0.33.0`
worked fine after updating to latest version (for now `0.36.0`).

@Jickson Thanks for your help.